# Monotouch: Controller brought to foreground - Notification?

Tags: notifications, xamarin.ios, foreground

MonoTouch

When an app is brought back to the foreground, I need the ViewController that becomes active to know about this.

Is there an event or override I can use to determine that the view was brought to the foreground.

I did find "WillEnterForegroundNotification" but it's a String, so am not sure how it's used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this:

Put this in the CTOR of the ViewController:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (UIApplication.WillEnterForegroundNotification, 
    EnterForeground);
```

Create then this method to handle the event in the view controller.

```
void EnterForeground (NSNotification notification)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EnterForeground: " + notification.Name); 
}
```

Note: When your app is brought to the foreground, the UIApplicationDelegate will get this raised first, a good place to clear things like login details and security related checks.

```
public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my MonoTouch app I have an "add" button that once tapped is then disabled for the rest of the day. To check and enable the button when the app becomes active I monitor `UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveDidBecomeActive` in the constructor for the ViewController.

```
NSObject _didBecomeActiveNotification;
.
.
.
// and in constructor
_didBecomeActiveNotification = UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveDidBecomeActive((sender, args) => {
    SetRightBarButtonState();
});
```

Then I override the `Dispose` method in the ViewController via

```
protected override void Dispose (bool disposing) {
    if (disposing) {
        _didBecomeActiveNotification.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose (disposing);
}
```